# How to loop through a generator

Tags: python, generator

How can one loop through a generator? I thought about this way:

```
gen = function_that_returns_a_generator(param1, param2)
if gen: # in case the generator is null
    while True:
        try:
            print gen.next()
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: I would suggest using `break`; not `continue`

Comment: I would actually do it this way in the case where the generator may throw an exception on an element, but you don't want to stop the iteration.

Comment: I would like to measure the execution time of each generator invocation. What's a reasonably elegant & pythonic way to structure a loop that can get the timestamp before and after each invocation?

Comment: Use variant was actually the best for my use case, but in Python 3 it has to be `gen.__next__()`.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Simply

```
for x in gen:
    # whatever
```

will do the trick.  Note that `if gen` always returns `True`.

Comment: No, `if gen` doesn't always return `True`. If the op's `function_that_returns_a_generator()` returns `None`, `gen` evaluates to `False` in the `if` statement.

Comment: @drevicko: I was assuming that `function_that_returns_a_generator()` returns a generator (bold assumption, isn't it?).  `None` is not a generator.

Comment: Since, OP asks for a "pythonic way", this answer seems pretty legit, given that Python advocates [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-eafp) ;-)

Answer (score 19):

In case you don't need the output of the generator because you care only about its side effects, you can use the following one-liner:

```
for _ in gen: pass
```

##### Follow up

Following the comment by aiven I made some performance tests, and while it seems that `list(gen)` is slightly faster than `for _ in gen: pass`, it comes out that `tuple(gen)` is even faster. However, as  Erik Aronesty correctly points out, `tuple(gen)` and `list(gen)` store the results, so my final advice is to use

```
tuple(gen)
```

but only if the generator is not going to loop billions of times soaking up too much memory.

Comment: or just `list(gen)`

Comment: tuple or list will store all the results.   if the generator is going to loop billions of times (some go infintiely), this isn't cool.

Answer (score 17):

```
for item in function_that_returns_a_generator(param1, param2):
    print item
```

You don't need to worry about the test to see if there is anything being returned by your function as if there's nothing returned you won't enter the loop.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply loop through it:

```
>>> gen = (i for i in range(1, 4))
>>> for i in gen: print i
1
2
3
```

But be aware, that you can only loop one time. Next time generator will be empty:

```
>>> for i in gen: print i
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

The other answers are good for complicated scenarios. If you simply want to stream the items into a list:

```py
x = list(generator)
```

For simple preprocessing, use list comprehensions:

```py
x = [tup[0] for tup in generator]
```

If you just want to execute the generator without saving the results, you can skip variable assignment:

```py
# no var assignment b/c we don't need what print() returns
[print(_) for _ in gen]
```

Don't do this if your generator is infinite (say, streaming items from the internet). The list construction is a blocking op that won't stop until the generator is empty.

Comment: I didn't note that generators are a one time thing, hence `list(generator)` is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Just treat it like any other iterable:

```
for val in function_that_returns_a_generator(p1, p2):
    print val
```

Note that `if gen:` will always be True, so it's a false test

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manually move through the generator (i.e., to work with each loop manually) then you could do something like this:

```
    from pdb import set_trace

    for x in gen:
        set_trace()
        #do whatever you want with x at the command prompt
        #use pdb commands to step through each loop of the generator e.g., >>c #continue
```

Comment: from pdb import set_trace # no ()  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a really complicated scenario like an array of commands, and want to avoid dealing with a list of `[None]*1000`, you can do something like this:

```
>>> d = {} # just a test-case scenario
>>> iterate = lambda *args: None # still invokes GC on (None)*1000
>>> iterate( *(d.__setitem__(k,None) for k in 'ABCDE') )
>>> d
{'A': None, 'D': None, 'C': None, 'B': None, 'E': None}
```

just for context to show the object being scrapped:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> iterate = lambda *args: print(args)
>>> iterate( *(d.__setitem__(k,None) for k in 'ABCDE') )
(None, None, None, None, None)
>>> d
{'A': None, 'D': None, 'C': None, 'B': None, 'E': None}
```