# Keras. figuring out class label encoding

Tags: keras

I am doing binary classification with one-output layer. I want to know which class is encoded as 0 and as 1 so that I can interpret probability scores when using model.predict() in Keras (which I think are scores for label1). Does it make sense to use predct_classes for training data to inspect the class label given that training loss is small? Is there any better way to this?

Comment: did you create the binary labels yourself or using sklearn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to use `predict(trainingData)` to study the results, to manually compare the values between the predicted data and the true data.

But it's you who define what 0 and 1 are when you create the true values.

The answer is in your true data, what they usually call "Y". The model will learn what is in Y and that is the classification. Only you (who created the data) can know that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used ImageDataGenerator and I didn't manually encode the labels. I figured out: class_indices did the trick, it shows the dictionary which maps name of sub-directory to the encoded labels. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3296

Comment: Maybe you can iterate the Generator once to see what Y it generates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539194/how-to-loop-through-a-generator --- `for X,Y in generatorInstance:`...